# How much does reforging cost on items that don't have a vendor sell price?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Reforging cost is equal to the sell price of an item to a vendor.

How do I determine the reforge price for an item that cannot be sold to a vendor (for example, items bought with tokens)?

Answer (score 4):

It costs a flat 10g for unsellable items that don't have a sell price listed on Wowhead and can not be sold to a vendor.

Comment: I verified this in-game and it seems correct. It's a flag 10g for a badge item.

Answer (score 2):

Every item has a Vendor sell price, even if the item is ineligible to be sold. You can look them up at [WoWhead](http://www.wowhead.com).

If you'd like to check in game, simply walk up to a Reforging and queue up a reforge without finalizing it. It will tell you the cost.

Comment: http://www.wowhead.com/item=40524

Comment: Wowheads data is incomplete. This is why I proposed the alternative means of checking.

Comment: I don't have WoW account to try it. Plus I need a way to calculate that price without a game.

Comment: I was told it's flat 10g fee for non-sellable items. Does that sound right?

Comment: @LessPop I just checked in-game and it looks like the OP's right. It's just a flat 10g fee, not a hidden sell price.

Comment: A flat 10g *is* a hidden sell price in this case. :P glad to see it answered.